# Jboss 5.1.0 hibernate 3.0.5 problem

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss5.x

I am trying to deploy a web application which is using hibernate 3.0.5 in JBOSS 5.1.0. I am running in to some problems. The same war file is working fine in jboss 4.0.3. In
/commons/lib has hibernate 3.3.1 jar file. But In my war file WEB-INF/lib folder I have hibernate-3.0.5.jar  .

Does jboss 5.1.0 will not work for hibernate 3.0.5 applications. Or do I need to do any specific configuration for this. Please suggest your solution.

Comment: can you post the exception, or at least the first part of it

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the hibernate jar files in jboss/commons/lib from your lib hibernate jars.

if you give the error log can give more comprehensive answer .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is I can't copy my hibernate jar in to Jboss lib folder. Since I have other war files which are using hibernate 3.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to delete hibernate jars from your web-application. 
If your app doesn't use any really specific features of that particular Hibernate version, chances are that it will work pretty well with newer version of Hibernate.

As a bonus, you will save a couple of megabytes in your war file.